# Using netcat as a simple CGI server

Tags: cgi, stdout, netcat

I was trying to use the following script to create a simple CGI server (from http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/netcat_inhalt.en.html). This more about the technical reason it's not working than whether this is a good idea:

```
#!/bin/bash
export port=${port:-$1} # inherit $1 as $port
/usr/local/bin/nc -l -p $port -e $0 &  # await further connections on this port
echo "hi"
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work properly? Upon first execution, it prints "hi" to the terminal, which I expect. I would then expect netcat to be waiting on the specified port, ready to spawn a new copy of this script with the STDOUT associated with the network socket (because of the -e flag). So HTTP GET requests to the specified port would then receive the text "hi".

What actually happens is that each GET request causes a new netcat process to be spawned, one at a time (which I expect), but none of the GET requests complete until I kill the latest netcat process. At that point, the first GET request I issued responds with "hi", and all the others come back as failed connection attempts. I suspect this has something to do with my confusion about the details of STDOUT redirection, but my understanding is that this script would just spawn a new version of itself every time someone connected, and the STDIN/OUT for the script should be the network socket because of the -e netcat flag.

Answer (score 0):

The -e option to netcat will not work unless it is compiled with -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE which should give you some pause as to the wisdom of doing things this way.  It's also an option that is only available in Hobbit's netcat and bsd-ish derivatives, not afaik in GNU netcat.

Could you achieve the desired result by piping your data into the netcat process?  For example

```
echo "hi" | nc -l -p $port
```

Seems to have largely the same effect, however the data is likely generated *before* the connection is made, rather than after as in using the -e flag.  If your data doesn't need to be time-based or interactive this would work.

Comment: I have compiled with -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE option enabled. It does  work when executing from the command line itself, but the script I mentioned is not performing as I would expect.

Comment: FWIW, your code seems to work for me, with the exception that I get a 'hi' in the terminal from which I launch it.  But I also get one delivered to the client (also netcat) that I connect to test it - which is presumably the goal.  But if at all possible, I'd still encourage piping input into netcat rather than using it to exec something.